# Check whether the four vectors forms a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Check whether the four vectors $\{(1, 1, 1, 1),(0, 1, 1, 1),(0, 0, 1, 1),(0, 0, 0, 1)\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ or not.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to solve this question, i converted the given vectors to a matrix and found is determinant is $1$. Since determinant is non zero, hence i concluded that it forms the basis for $\Bbb R^4$.

I want to know is the method correct or should I use the spanning method.
Also is there any other way to solve this question?

Comment: Yes, the method is correct.

Comment: @Fakemistake thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form 4*4 martix  and apply elementary row operation. If that matrix is of rank 4 then they are linearly independent.

Another method is that
A=(1,1,1,1), B=(0,1,1,1) ,C=(0,0,1,1), D=(0,0,0,1)
Now C is not scalar multiple of D.
So C and D are l.i. B is not scalar multiple of C and D.So B,C,D are l.i.
Finally A is not scalar multiple of B,C,D.
So all are l.i.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.

You can also transform that matrix in reduced row echelon form and check that you get the identity matrix.